# Cannot assign the second sql alias

Tags: sql, db2, alias, squirrel-sql

I am having difficulties getting my second alias to work in the example below.
I'm using Squirrel SQL 3.7

Getting an error

> Error: [SQL5001] Column qualifier or table T2 undefined. SQLState: 
>   42703 ErrorCode: -5001

```
UPDATE myDatabaseOne.myTableOne t1
SET 
    firstFieldToCopy = (SELECT DISTINCT alternateField FROM myDatabaseTwo.myTableTwo t2)
WHERE t1.firstFieldToCopy = t2.alternateField;
```

Comment: your logic is off a little.. need to show us what your data looks like and what you're trying to change it to.. I have no idea why people are answering this question based on the query you've provided

Comment: @JamieD77 Well, the answers all answers why he's getting the error he's getting. The fact that the question is hazy doesn't make the relevant error less obvious.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard  well the first answer by josh is probably the correct path.. not sure what the distinct is for.. the second answer by Aaron probably won't compile in db2.. i guess yours has some helpful information..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean...

```
UPDATE myDatabaseOne.myTableOne t1
    SET firstFieldToCopy = (SELECT DISTINCT alternateField 
        FROM myDatabaseTwo.myTableTwo t2
        WHERE t1.firstFieldToCopy = t2.alternateField);
```

Note the position of the )  ... This is why the t2 alias didn't work...

Otherwise the query is confusing as to your intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.firstfieldtocopy = t2.alternatefield
FROM mydatabaseone.mytableone t1
JOIN mydatabasetwo.mytabletwo t2 on t1.firstfieldtocopy = t2.alternate field
```

I don't understand your logic though.. Setting copy = alternate but you're filtering to where copy = alternate already.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with scoping. `t2` is only accessible within

```
(SELECT DISTINCT alternateField FROM myDatabaseTwo.myTableTwo t2)
```

which means that when you say `WHERE t1.firstFieldToCopy = t2.alternateField` your DBMS has no clues what you're referring to.

There are still 2 issues to the query though :

1. Your subquery most probably returns 2+ values since `DISTINCT` isn't used to return a single value, but to eliminate duplicates.
2. You're overriding old values with identical new values (see Aaron D's answer).